Can reach network devices via Wi-Fi but not powerline
I have the following devices:

Win10 laptop
Fritzbox 6590 Cable router
Synology DS218j connected directly to the router
a set of TP-Link TL-PA7017P AV1000 powerline adapters connected to the router and my laptop, respectively

When my laptop is connected via Wi-Fi, I can find/access the router and the NAS at 192.168.178.x without any problems.
When I'm connected via the TP-Link powerline adapters, I can access the internet but I cannot reach the router or the NAS. arp -a does not list the devices.
Any ideas what might be wrong in my configuration?
Thanks!
Edit: I noticed something weird. When connected via powerline, I cannot reach some websites either, e.g., reddit.com or superuser.com. Most others, e.g. google.com, work.

Can you run a test with your laptop on Ethernet directly to a LAN port on your main router, without the powerline equipment in between? Powerline is not Ethernet and powerline adapters are infamous for being flaky in various ways.

Okay, sorry, I didn't know that. Everything works perfectly when I connect the laptop directly to the router via ethernet (not powerline).
